# Displaying Map key value pair in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a @AuraEnabled method which will return value of type Map
How can we display Map's key value pairs in lightning component?
for eg :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static map<String,Integer> getDensityOfObject(String strField, String strObj) 
    {
        system.debug('----strField----'+strField);
        system.debug('----strObj----'+strObj);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mapFieldNameToFieldDesc = new Map<String,Schema.SObjectField>();
        gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 

        if(String.isNotBlank(strField) && String.isNotBlank(strObj))
        {
            if(!gd.containsKey(strObj.toLowerCase()))
            {
                throw new System.NoAccessException();
                return  null;
            }else
            {
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R =gd.get(strObj).getDescribe();
                mapFieldNameToFieldDesc = R.fields.getMap();
                if(!mapFieldNameToFieldDesc.containsKey(strField.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    throw new System.NoAccessException();
                    return null;
                }
            }

        }
        map<String,Integer> mapStrState_intCount = new map<String,Integer>();
        Set<String> setStates = new Set<String>();

        setStates.addAll(map_AbbreviationToStateName.values());

        for(Sobject objSobject : getAllSobjectRecords(strField,strObj))
        {
                if(map_AbbreviationToStateName.containsKey(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                {
                    if(!mapStrState_intCount.containsKey(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                        mapStrState_intCount.put(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)) , 1 );
                    else
                    mapStrState_intCount.put(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)), mapStrState_intCount.get(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)))+1);

                }
                else if(setStates.contains(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                {
                    for(String abbr : map_AbbreviationToStateName.keySet())
                    {
                        if(map_AbbreviationToStateName.get(abbr) == String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)))
                        {
                              if(!mapStrState_intCount.containsKey(abbr))
                                mapStrState_intCount.put(abbr , 1 );
                            else
                                mapStrState_intCount.put(abbr, mapStrState_intCount.get(abbr)+1);
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
        system.debug('mapStrState_intCount-----'+mapStrState_intCount);
        return mapStrState_intCount;
    }
```

---

```
({  
    initMap : function(component, event) 
    { 
        var action = component.get("c.getDensityOfObject");
        action.setParams({ "strField": component.get("v.strFieldName")  ,
                          "strObj" : component.get("v.strObjName")});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response)
        {
            var result = response.getState();

            if (result === "SUCCESS") 
            {
                var myMap = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.stateWithCount",myMap);
             }      
         } 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 

    }
})
```

As you can see here, I am getting map value in helper js. 
component.set`("v.stateWithCount",myMap)`;
Now on component I want to display key-value pair from v.stateWithCount

Comment: At what step are you blocked? Getting the Data?  Getting the data into a javascript helper method? Outputting to your components element? Or are you curious how to do this via the cmp markup?

Comment: @KrisGray I have edited my question. Please have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done in just pure JavaScript, if you were looking for the way to do it using the component tags, I'm not sure of a built in way to do that.

Since setting the property on your component should trigger a rerender, you should be able to put this code in your afterRender function like so.

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, theMap) {
        var element = component.getElement();
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        var li;
        var text;
        for(var prop in theMap) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            text = document.createTextNode(prop + ": " + theMap[prop]);
            li.appendChild(text);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        element.appendChild(ul);
        return this.superAfterRender();
    }
});
```

Looking for something different?

Comment: I am just bit confused about how to use this. Can you please provide component code too? Or give me sample demo code of overall concept for displaying map on Component.

Comment: Your component won't need much, just a <div></div>

Comment: There is one section for a Component called "Rerender". Do I need to copy this code there? If so how to call this method ?
Or are you suggesting to use this in helper? 
Sorry I am new to Lightning, so things are messed up!

Comment: It gets called automatically. So yea just put this in there.

Comment: @KrisGray are you sure you can do this **var ul = document.createElement("ul");..element.appendChild(ul);** when Locker Service is enabled?

Comment: @DenisPereverzev - I can conform that this works well with Locker Service enabled.